# Prove that a given set is finite in topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm given a topology on an uncountable set $X$, $a \in X$ and a topology defined in terms of closed sets by a collection of sets, $F$, that each satisfy either $a \in F$ or $F$ is countable.

I'm trying to deduce that if given a sequence $x_n$ converging to $l \in F$ then the set $\{x_n : x_n \ne l\}$ is finite.

I'm struggling to make any progress with this. From the definition of convergence I know that we can choose N sufficiently large to keep $x_n$ out of any countable set but that is about as far as I have managed to get.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "$l \in F$", what do you mean?  $F$ was a placeholder in the definition of an unnamed collection of sets.

Comment: Why do you assume $l ∈ F$? What is $F$?

Comment: @EricTowers $F$ is a placeholder name for an arbitrary closed set. Note the OP says "the collection of sets $F$", not "the collection $F$ of sets". Yes, this question could benefit from some rephrasing. But I found it rather obvious what was meant.

Comment: Ah yes, I could have been more clear in the question. Have edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that $x_n$ converges to $l$ means that for *any* open set $U$ containing $l$, there is an $N$ so that $x_n \in U$ for all $n \geq N$.

Assuming it *does* converge to some $l$, take the open set $V = \left(X \setminus \{x_n \mid n \in \Bbb N\}\right)\cup \{l, a\}$. This set is open since the complement is at most countable, and it contains $l$ since I specifically included it. That means that eventually, all $x_n$ must be in $V$, but apart from $l$ we've removed all points of the sequence from the neighbourhood.

Therefore, if the sequence isn't eventually constantly equal to $l$, it does not converge to $l$, since I've just constructed a neighbourhood that doesn't eventually contain the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $\{x_n: x_n ≠ l\}$ is infinite, then there is a subsequence which does not contain $l$.